Image of a system of nonlinear inequalities under a linear map
Suppose we have a nonlinear feasible set $F$ in $\mathbb R^8$ given by
all $(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}, y_{11},y_{12},y_{21},y_{22})$
satisfying
$x_{ij},y_{ij}\geq 0$ and
$x_{ij}^2+y_{ij}^2\leq 1$, for all $i,j$
Define a linear map  $L:\mathbb R^8\to \mathbb R^4$ by
$X_i= x_{i1}+x_{i2}$,  $ i=1,2$
$Y_j= y_{1j}+y_{2j}$,  $ j=1,2$
How can I completely characterize the inequalities that define the image set $G=LF$, i.e.,  $$G=\{(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)\in \mathbb R^4:   \exists (x,y)\in F\,\,\text{ such that}\,\,   (X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)=L (x,y)\}$$
I think Farkas lemma and network flow can be useful when $F$ is linear system. I wonder if there is some mathematical approach or literature to sovle this problem when $F$ is nonlinear like the above case? Thanks.

Just wonder for what purpose do you want to characterize the set G?

Hi, I want to do optimization over the set $G$, where $(X,Y)$ are variables. I have other constraints $S$ on $(X,Y)$, so I need to know the set $G$.

You probably know Convexity is preserved under linear transformation. Besides that, I'm not sure how much more we can guarantee (not even distance, shape, area, etc).
